# Preventing access to service instances in Angular

Tags: angular

Quick and probably a simple question but I'm having trouble finding an answer searching the interwebs.

Using the Angular 4.x in my app and I have a core module that I keep my singleton services in. I also have some services that wrap some third party sdk's and I don't want those wrapping services to be accessible to my feature modules. But since I have to provide these services in order to use them that makes them available for injection in components and services outside my core module.

How can I keep these services private within my core module?

Comment: This will help you understand how Angular handles providers  on te module level [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f). You can ask clarification questions then if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to limit access is to define the scope.
The scope depends on where a service is provided.
If a service is provided on a component or directive, only the component or descendants can inject it.

If the service is provided on a module it becomes globally available.

If the service is provided on a lazy loaded module, only this module and modules loaded together with this lazy loaded module can inject the service.

There are no other ways to limit where a service can be injected.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I already knew this but was hoping that there was some trick that I was not aware of. I guess I'm just stuck with it like it is.